# How to disable Google play services by code?

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am creating an app where I need to analyse spector of my signal. And when this service is on I got some filtered HZs, When I stop this service everything is ok.
In my app I need to disable Google play services by code when my app runs.
Is there any idea how can disable  the services (Force Stop) by code ?

Comment: why do you want to do that?

Comment: I am creating an app where I need to analyse spector of my signal. And when this service is on I got some filtered HZs, When I stop this service everything is ok

Comment: include this detail in question itself to support your question.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not allowed to force a stop of Google Play services by design and by contract. You can connect and disconnect your own clients at-will, but other apps on the device may be using the services and you are not allowed to interfere with them.

What services on the phone are you using that you suspect Google Play services is interfering with?

Comment: Stop Google Play Music service because after plugging the headphone it starts and I don't need that

Comment: This has nothing to do with Google Play services.

Answer (score 0):

According to the android documentation: The `GoogleApiClient` class is **The main entry point for Google Play services integration.**

So in order to disable Google Play Services functionality. Try calling `GoogleApiClient.disconnect();` on your `GoogleApiClient` object.

Hopefully that should work.